# Is functions in redux reducers ok?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am writing some reducers with Redux-Sagas, Im quite new to this and all reducers we have now dont have any thing like I am about to do. Started to question myself if its the right thing to do.

In this case I have an INITIAL_STATE thats contains a dataProp, this data has an prop that is an array of users. Now I create a editUser form, when the user is updated I get the updated user back. to update that user in the ReactView I do like this:

```
const updateUser = (users, user) => {
                //Update user and return array
               };

   [actions.updateUserSuccess]: (state, payload) => ({
            ...state,
            viewData: {
                ...state.viewData,
                users: updateUser(...state.viewData.Users, payload)
            },
            loadingUser: false,
        }),
```

And the question, is it ok to put a method to handle a thing like this on top of the reducer file?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can structure reducers however you like. What matters is the code inside that function, is it safe? Is it mutating the objects? Is it pure? etc.

Comment: Note that there's a possible issue with your function, where you're spreading the initial users when calling it, but you're assuming you'll receive the array as a first param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that's totally fine, and in fact [we have a docs page on "SplittingReducer Logic"](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/splitting-reducer-logic) that even talks about that.

That said, you really *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your Redux logic.  It will greatly simplify *all* your Redux code.  In particular, it uses Immer to let you write "mutating" syntax in your reducers, and turns that into safe and correct immutable updates.  No more object spreads!

Comment: I wouldnt use the word 'simplify', its verbose but efficient and easily enables scaling best practices :p

Comment: I would _absolutely_ use the word "simplify". RTK removes the need to write any action creators or action types by hand, shrinks the typical store setup sequence down to a single `configureStore()` call, and eliminates the need to hand-write immutable updates. Those all definitely qualify as "simplifying" the code and eliminating that "verbosity".

Comment: Its probably not the correct place to discuss that (although I think its interesting ! :)). And I did not meant reduxtoolkit is bad, I use it on every project now, ;)

Answer (score 2):

When using functions like that in legacy switch..case reducers, you always have to be very aware if those functions are "safe", which means they cannot modify anything and have to return a modified copy of the original.

I would recommend to refactor that reducer to a ["modern Redux" `createSlice`](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createslice) reducer since in those you can just modify all objects without problems - also that style of reducer is the official recommendation for all Redux code since 2019 anyways. In such a reducer you can use all functions without having to care too much.

Of course you should still avoid side effects, that goes for all reducers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create any helper functions and use them inside your reducers.

As long as you [DON'T mutate](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#reducers-and-immutable-updates) state directly in your reducers or in those functions, that's fine.